# Material UI - How to animate Card depth on hover?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to animate the depth of the whole `Card` when the mouse is over it.
I try this (so-so I'm new in React) but I have no idea how to do it:

```
<Card 
  linkButton={true}
  href="/servicios/"
  onClick={Link.handleClick} zDepth={3}
  onMouseEnter={this.setState({zDepth={1}})}>
</Card>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can only use the props that that material-ui gives you, cards dont have zdepth, but you can put the whole care in a paper component and then add it there

Comment: It rediculous that MUI doesnt provide a enableHover or something. It blows complexity to keep state of the hover state in order to trigger elevation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { shadow: 1 }
}

onMouseOver = () => this.setState({ shadow: 3 });
onMouseOut = () => this.setState({ shadow: 1 });

<Card 
   onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
   onMouseOut={this.onMouseOut}
   zDepth={this.state.shadow}
>
```

Updated #1

Full example

```
// StyledCard.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card } from 'material-ui/Card';

class StyledCard extends Component {
  state: {
    shadow: 1
  }

  onMouseOver = () => this.setState({ shadow: 3 });

  onMouseOut = () => this.setState({ shadow: 1 });

  render() {
    return (
      <Card 
        onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
        onMouseOut={this.onMouseOut}
        zDepth={this.state.shadow}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Card>
    );
  }

export default StyledCard;
```

.

```
// Container.js

import React from 'react';
import StyledCard from './StyledCard';

const Container = () => [
  <StyledCard>Card 1</StyledCard>,
  <StyledCard>Card 2</StyledCard>,
  <StyledCard>Card 3</StyledCard>,
];

export default Container;
```

UPDATED #2

With HOC

```
// withShadow.js

import React from 'react';

const withShadow = (Component, { init = 1, hovered = 3 }) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    state: {
      shadow: init
    };

    onMouseOver = () => this.setState({ shadow: hovered });

    onMouseOut = () => this.setState({ shadow: init });

    render() {
      return (
        <Component
          onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
          onMouseOut={this.onMouseOut}
          zDepth={this.state.shadow}
          {...this.props}
        />
      );
    }
  };
};

export default withShadow;
```

.

```
// Container.js

import React from 'react';
import { Card } from 'material-ui/Card';
import withShadow from './withShadow';

const CardWithShadow = withShadow(Card, { init: 2, hovered: 4 });

const Container = () => [
  <CardWithShadow>Card 1</CardWithShadow>,
  <CardWithShadow>Card 2</CardWithShadow>,
  <CardWithShadow>Card 3</CardWithShadow>,
];

export default Container;
```

Comment: This works. However, if I have multiple cards, then hovering on one card, changes the state and hence changes depth of all the cards. How can this be done when you have multiple cards?

Comment: @SeaWarrior404, do you have a solution for your issue? I am encountering it right now

Answer (score 29):

5 years later and there is still no correct answer, you do not have to set the component state when it hovers, just use the pseudo-class `:hover`:

```
<Card
  sx={{
    ':hover': {
      boxShadow: 20, // theme.shadows[20]
    },
  }}
>
```

If you want to use [`styled()`](https://mui.com/system/styled/#main-content):

```
const options = {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'hoverShadow',
};
const StyledCard = styled(
  Card,
  options,
)(({ theme, hoverShadow = 1 }) => ({
  ':hover': {
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[hoverShadow],
  },
}));
```

```
<StyledCard hoverShadow={10}>
  <Content />
</StyledCard>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted.  Using JS events to track the hover state just to modify CSS is a hack.

Answer (score 14):

@Alex Sandiiarov answer didnt work for me. The docs show to use the `raised` property.
 https://material-ui.com/api/card/

```
class Component extends React.Component{

  state = {
    raised:false
  }

  toggleRaised = () => this.setState({raised:!this.state.raised});

  render(){
    return <Card onMouseOver={this.toggleRaised} 
      onMouseOut={this.toggleRaised} 
      raised={this.state.raised}>

      ...

      </Card>

  }
}
```

Comment: FYI your code doesn't compile. You're missing a `}` on your toggleRaised function.

Comment: @haaduken Good spot

Comment: @MadisonCourto I am a bit confused... just do `<Paper raised="99" />`

Comment: According to the docs you can use Paper API as well to add more props to the component, so you can use "elevation" `<Card evelation={5}>` https://material-ui.com/api/paper